worksheet.add_format() formatting my headers
I'm trying to format my df so the data has 4 decimal places, but it keeps formating my headers also. Is it possible to skip the first row while worksheet.add_format()?
DataFrame:
DateReferencia  2023    2024    2025    2026    2027    2028
Date                        
02/01/2024  2.9233  1.5500  2.0 2.0 2.0 NaN
03/01/2024  2.9233  1.5500  2.0 2.0 2.0 NaN
04/01/2024  2.9313  1.5872  2.0 2.0 2.0 NaN
05/01/2024  2.9221  1.5872  2.0 2.0 2.0 NaN
08/01/2024  2.9208  1.5922  2.0 2.0 2.0 NaN

Code to format and send the df to excel:
writer = pd.ExcelWriter("pandas_column_formats.xlsx", engine="xlsxwriter")
df.to_excel(writer, sheet_name='Sheet1')


workbook = writer.book
worksheet = writer.sheets["Sheet1"]

format1 = workbook.add_format({"num_format": "0.0000"})
worksheet.set_column(1,len(df), None, format1)
writer.close()

OutPut:
DateReferencia 2,023.0000   2,024.0000  2,025.0000  2,026.0000  2,027.0000  2,028.0000
Date
02/01/2024  2.9233  1.5500  2.0000  2.0000  2.0000  
03/01/2024  2.9233  1.5500  2.0000  2.0000  2.0000  
04/01/2024  2.9313  1.5872  2.0000  2.0000  2.0000  
05/01/2024  2.9221  1.5872  2.0000  2.0000  2.0000  
08/01/2024  2.9208  1.5922  2.0000  2.0000  2.0000  


That shouldn't happen. The column headers should be written as strings and as such the number format shouldn't be applied. Also, the fact that "Date" is on a separate line suggests a multi-index or some other manipulation. Could you update your question to add a sample dataframe so we can see what is going on.

pandas already applies some cell formats to the headers and rows, so you should check this official page: https://xlsxwriter.readthedocs.io/working_with_pandas.html#formatting-of-the-dataframe-headers (TLDR: write the data without the headers first, then add the headers with a custom format)
I couldn't replicate your issue with the code you provided, so it could also be specific to the versions of pandas and xlsxwriter you are using. You can try the following steps:

Follow the official recommendation and write data + headers separately with different formatters
Set the headers as strings to avoid the formatting (e.g.
df.columns = df.columns.astype(str))
Adjust the values in the dataframe before exporting it (e.g. df = df.applymap(lambda x: f"{x:.4f}" if isinstance(x, (int,float)) else x))

